# Why this error message appear?: invalid get index 'game_started' (on base: 'Node')

Tags: game-engine, game-physics, godot, gdscript

can you please help me, I have this script:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var motion = Vector2(0, 300)

var sensitivity = 13
onready var player = get_node("../Player")
onready var enemy = get_node("../Enemy")


func _ready():
    randomize()
    reset_ball()

func _physics_process(delta):
    if not get_parent().game_started:
        return
    if is_on_wall():
        motion.x *= -1
    
    
    if is_on_floor():
        touch_someone(player)
    if is_on_ceiling():
        touch_someone(enemy)
    
    move_and_slide(motion, Vector2(0, -1))


func touch_someone(node):
    motion.y *= -1
    motion.x = (position.x - node.position.x) * sensitivity

func reset_ball():
    motion.x = rand_range(-300, 300)
```

nd when I run the game this error message appears
invalid get index 'game_started' (on base: 'Node').

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4m1O.png)

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that there isn't a `game_started` defined in the parent node. There is a parent node, but it does not have a property `game_started` defined.

You probably intended it to be a property, but you forgot to define it, defined it somewhere else, or you did define it in the correct place, but instanced the node under the wrong parent. *However, it is also possible you made it a method and simply forgot `()`. I don't know which is the case.*

Regardless, in Godot, a common design pattern is to access down and signal up the scene tree. In this case, you are trying to access up the scene tree. This is problematic because the scene can't ensure where it will be instanced.

I'll give you a few approaches to solve this problem:

- **Check if `game_started` exists.**

  The change that will have a smaller impact on your architecture is to check if the parent node has `game_started` before trying to read it. Which looks something like this:

  ```
  var parent = get_parent
  if !"game_started" in parent or !parent.game_started:
      return
  ```

  However please notice that even if this gets rid of the error, it is not fixing the source of the problem. Since `game_started` is not defined in the parent anyway.

  Furthermore, `_physics_process` is still getting called. There are ways to don't even have the call, which is better for performance. Will come back to that.
- **Let the parent access the child.**

  What you want to accomplish is to enable and disable `_physics_process` based on the value of `game_started`. There is a way to enable and disable `_physics_process` in the engine: [`set_physics_process`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-set-physics-process).

  Presumably there is some other code somewhere that sets `game_started` on the parent, in that moment it could call `set_physics_process` on the child to disable or enable `_physics_process` accordingly.

  You may even use a property (with [`setget`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html?highlight=setget#setters-getters)) to this effect.

  For example:

  ```
  var game_started:bool setget set_game_started

  func set_game_started(new_value:bool) -> void:
      if game_started == new_value:
          return

      for child in get_children():
          child.set_physics_process(new_value)

      game_started = new_value
  ```

  With this, your script does not have to check `game_started`. One drawback is that the code only uses `set_physics_process` on the direct children. We could write a recursive version, however, we can do better!
- **Use pause.**

  As you can see in [pausing games](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/misc/pausing_games.html), you can use `get_tree().paused` to get or set if the game is paused. Which will stop `_physics_process` (among other methods) depending on the [`pause_mode`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-property-pause-mode).

  Thus, you can have the parent update `get_tree().paused`...

  Assuming, you also want a pause, you may follow this pattern:

  ```
  var game_started:bool setget set_game_started
  var game_paused:bool setget set_game_paused

  func set_game_started(new_value:bool) -> void:
      game_started = new_value
      update_pause()

  func set_game_paused(new_value:bool) -> void:
      game_paused = new_value
      update_pause()

  func update_pause() -> void:
      get_tree().paused = !game_started or game_paused
  ```

  Then, for the nodes that should still work when the game is paused or not started, you can se `pause_mode = PAUSE_MODE_PROCESS` so they don't get `_physics_process` et.al. disabled. Then they can check `game_started` and `game_paused` to distinguish if the game is paused or not started.

  A drawback is that this will affect nodes everywhere… If only `game_started` and `game_paused` could be available everywhere… Well, we can do that too!
- **Use an autoload.**

  Make an [autoload](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html) (via project settings) of a scene with a node that has `game_started` et.al. So that it is available from everywhere. Then you can access it from everywhere.

  You can do this combined with the `paused` as explained above. Which is what I would recommend.

  Alternatively. Since you can access it from everywhere, you you could simply access it instead of the parent:

  ```
  if !autoload_name.game_started:
      return
  ```

  *This is the exception to the access down and signal up rule. Since the autoload is available everywhere and it does not depend on where or how the scene was instanced.*

  *I remind you, is that `paused` and `set_physics_process` will avoid the call to `_physics_process`, and thus are more performant than checking this way.*